# email from address

Tags: email, email-client

i notice most websites like twitter uses long funny from email address when you request a forgotten password. the email address looks like this

> resetpw-ahgglavooyrf1984=ubgznvy.pbz-93f2e@postmaster.twitter.com

why is it so??

Comment: Super User is for questions about computer software and hardware. This is not about either and is therefore off topic.

Comment: @Mark: Is the Internet not "software"?

Comment: See [Bounce Address Tag Validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_Address_Tag_Validation).